# service mongod start doesnt start the mongod service

Tags: mongodb

I created a one click application mongoapp using digital ocean.I modified the /etc/mongod.conf file .I stopped the service and tried to start again but throws the following error,

> Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted

I tried to delete it but there is no sock file in tmp.I tried all the methods suggested in other questions.Could anyone please help me fix this error?

Comment: Can you try doing sudo service mongod start?

Comment: tried but same error